# I'm not using count but my log told me "count syntax error"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a request who look like this in PHP:

```
SELECT 
   CONTACT.NOM, 
   CONTACT.PRENOM,
   CONTACT.TITRE, 
   CONTACT.COMMENT2, 
   CONTACT.TEL, 
   CONTACT.FAX, 
   CONTACT.EMAIL, 
   SERVICES.NOM AS SERV 
FROM 
   CONTACT, SERVICES
WHERE 
   CONTACT.SECLEUNIK = SERVICES.SECLEUNIK AND 
   CONTACT.CLCLEUNIK = :idClient AND 
   (
      CONTACT.NOM LIKE %:nom% COLLATE FRENCH_CI_AI OR 
      CONTACT.PRENOM LIKE %:prenom% COLLATE FRENCH_CI_AI
   )

$prepare->execute(array(
            ':idClient' => $idClient,
            ':nom' => $nomClient

          ));
```

My logs give me this error:

> COUNT field incorrect or syntax error" at /var/www/WebService/src/Controller/DefaultController.php line 893

The line 893 is : `':nom' => $nomClient`, I don't understand why there is a "count" in the error, and don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: It's not answering the question, but you've had 28 years to start using the ANSI-92 JOIN Syntax; it's long past time you started to. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You need to bind 3 parameters for the statement - `:idClient`, `:nom` and `:prenom`.

Comment: `LIKE '%' + :prenom + '%'`..

Comment: @Zhorov "Syntaxe incorrecte vers '@P2'", now I have this error, and I don't understand because this request was created one month ago and work but since today it's dont work anymore

Comment: @jarlh ok you resolve it thank's post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the like wildcards to the parameters, e.g.:

```
LIKE '%' + :prenom + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the actual reason for your error is the fact, that you have three parameters in your statement (`:idClient`, `:nom` and `:prenom`), but you are passing two in the `execute()` method.

Also, you need to use `LIKE` operator correctly and change the statement with appropriate `JOIN` syntax:

Statement (based on the code in the question):

```
SELECT 
    CONTACT.NOM, 
    CONTACT.PRENOM,
    CONTACT.TITRE, 
    CONTACT.COMMENT2, 
    CONTACT.TEL, 
    CONTACT.FAX, 
    CONTACT.EMAIL, 
    SERVICES.NOM AS SERV 
FROM CONTACT 
INNER JOIN SERVICES ON SERVICES.SECLEUNIK = CONTACT.SECLEUNIK
WHERE 
    CONTACT.CLCLEUNIK = :idClient AND 
    (
        CONTACT.NOM LIKE CONCAT('%', :nom, '%') COLLATE FRENCH_CI_AI OR 
        CONTACT.PRENOM LIKE CONCAT('%', :prenom, '%') COLLATE FRENCH_CI_AI
    )
```

PHP:

```
<?php

...
$prepare->execute(
   array(
      ':idClient' => $idClient,
      ':nom' => $nomClient,
      ':prenom' => $prenomClient 
   )
);
...

?>
```